Error Running Flutter Mobile Application: Issue with :path_provider_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
I am encountering an issue while trying to run my Flutter mobile application. When I execute the project, I receive the following error message:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':path_provider_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.


Could not determine the dependencies of null.
Cannot query the value of this provider because it has no value available.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 4s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Expected Behavior:
I expect the application to run successfully and display a simple Flutter UI.
Actual Behavior:
However, I receive the error above message
here is my pubspec.yaml file:
name: flutter_application_1
description: "A new Flutter project."
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev


version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ^3.6.0-326.0.dev
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.8
  http: ^1.2.2
  flutter_secure_storage: ^9.2.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^5.0.0


flutter:

  uses-material-design: true


Try flutter pub cache clean , flutter pub cache repair, flutter pub get
